# Generate a report using Tibco Spotfire Desktop 7.6.0 for Transaction logs

Tags: spotfire

I have my syslogs which has translogs ( Ip address, Incoming URl, timestamp etc) in a text format. I want to generate a report using Tibco Spotfire Desktop 7.6.0. Can any one help me in understanding how to do it?

Comment: which syslogs? Spotfire has the ability to log everything that happens into a SQL table called ACTION_LOG that is nice to use for audit, performance, etc. Aside from that, you can import your logs if you can get them into csv format but you need to have a good understanding of the logs and how to read them.

Comment: Too less info to help you my friend. Please write as much as possible and pictures if you can.

Comment: DataPower transaction logs which is raw comma separated text file. It has DataPower IP address, Timestamp, Reason code, incoming URI Method, loadbalancer group information, load balancer member, text type etc. so, I want to process this file and should be able to generate report. Could you help me with this?

Comment: xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; an I generate a report using this kind of data

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not complicated at all. I don't have translog within easy reach but I have a classic Log4j file which contains the following information :

```
2016-01-17 12:25:08,594 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@72015cb3] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-01-17 12:25:08,648 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-01-17 12:25:08,670 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7641 ms
2016-01-17 12:25:08,736 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-01-17 12:25:08,739 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Sun Jan 17 12:25:08 GMT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2016-01-17 12:25:08,741 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/spring-rest.xml]
```

If you would like to read this file as a datasource and represent it as a graph, you have to:

1. Click on File / Add Data tables

[image]

2. Select Add / File, select your file

[image]

3. Enter the name and click on OK

[image]

4. That's it, the file is automatically spitted with the right column

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps.

---

EDIT : Comma separator file.

If you follow the same procedure with a comma sperated file like this

```
attribute1,attribute2,attribute3,attribute4
2016-01-01,1, row1, 1000
2016-01-01,1, row2, 2000
2016-01-02,1, row3, 3000
```

The import file will look like this
[image]

And it's still working fine
[image]

---

EDIT : Syslog

I tried with your sample, I just changed a couple of information (date and status code : 200, 404, ...)

```
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-26T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-27T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-27T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=404 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml; 
xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-27T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=404 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml;
```

You can import the file using the same method (Add Data table / File / Space separator). I obtain that :

[image]

Then if you want to split more with other rules (other separator, substring, ...). One solution consist in creating come calculated columns.

[image]

For example, I tried to extract the code (404, 200) with a rule  Right(col, length)

Result :
[image]

Comment: Awesome.. very nicely explained.

Comment: DataPower transaction logs which is raw comma separated text file. It has DataPower IP address, Timestamp, Reason code, incoming URI Method, loadbalancer group information, load balancer member, text type etc. so, I want to process this file may be some kind of parsing and should be able to generate report. In this scenario, can I follow the above method?

Comment: I edited the post at the end. A comma delimiter log file works fine as well.

Comment: xi52 11.10.12.22 2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00 [MKT][0x80000001][DPTransLog][info] wsgw(LTY-USL-v01): trans(353681927)[response][10.10.44.20] gtid(353681927):2016-05-25T16:01:09-04:00,tid=353681927,stat=ok,bk_res_code=200 OK,ClntIp=10.72.44.85,nuri=/Loyalty/Services/USLGTWY/LTY_USL_v10 ,intype=text/xml;charset=UTF-8,outtype=text/xml;   My data is something like this..

Comment: Hi. I added a solution which consist in importing your syslog file with a space separator and added some calculated column to extract specific data in a column.